# Не полностью выполняется условие

Tags: php, алгоритм

```
<?php
require('medoo.php');
set_time_limit(0);

define('BOT_TOKEN', '************************');
define('API_URL', 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.BOT_TOKEN.'/');


function sendKeyboard($db, $message, $chatID) {
    $replyMarkup = array(
        'keyboard' => array_chunk($db, 2));
    $keyboard = json_encode($replyMarkup);
    file_get_contents(API_URL."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chatID."&text=".$message."&reply_markup=".$keyboard);
}

$content = file_get_contents("php://input");
$update = json_decode($content, true);
$chatID = $update["message"]["chat"]["id"];
$chatText = $update["message"]["text"];

$database = new medoo(array(
    'database_type' => 'mysql',
    'database_name' => 'polls',
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '****************'
));

$redis = new Redis();
$redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
$redis->select(3);
$key_name = "user:".$chatID;
$getKey = $redis->get($key_name);
    if ($getKey) {
    // verify answer

    $getAnswer = $database->get('answers', '*', ["AND"=>['id_poll_answer' =>$getKey, 'description_answer'=>$chatText]]);
    if ($getAnswer) {
        // insert result
        $insAnswer = $database->insert('records', ['r_poll_id'=> $getKey, 'r_answer_id'=>$getAnswer['id_answer'], 'user_id'=>$chatID]);
        // delete key
        $redis->del($key_name);
        // show question keyboard
        $getAllPoll = $database->select('polls', 'name_poll');
        sendKeyboard($getAllPoll, "Спасибо, Ваш ответ засчитан!", $chatID);
    } else {
        // oww, wrong answer
        $getAllAnsw = $database->select('answers' ,'description_answer', ['id_poll_answer'=> $getKey]);
        sendKeyboard($getAllAnsw, "Такого ответа нет! Попробуйте ещё раз.", $chatID);
    }
} else {
    // verify answer
    //TODO: show question keyboard
    $getAllPoll = $database->select('polls', 'name_poll');
    sendKeyboard($getAllPoll,"Выберите опрос", $chatID);
    $getPoll = $database->get('polls', '*', ['name_poll'=> $chatText]);

    if($getPoll){
        $redis->set($key_name, $getPoll['id_poll']);
        $getAllAnsw = $database->select('answers' ,'description_answer', ['id_poll_answer'=> $getKey]);
        sendKeyboard($getAllAnsw, "Выберите ответ", $chatID);

    }
    else {

    }
    }
```

Comment: В комментариях указана строка, которая почему то не выполняется.

Comment: А всё остальное выполняется? В этом же условии строка выше или другая строка с такой же функцией?

Comment: да, строка $redis->set($key_name, $getPoll['id_poll']); выполняется, а потом опять срабатывает sendKeyboard($getAllPoll,"Выберите опрос", $chatID);

Comment: Вывод ошибок включен?

Comment: я смотрю в /var/log/nginx/error.log  и там ошибок нет

Comment: А уровень ошибок какой?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Вас не смущает что в вашей строке переменной `$getAllAnsw` не существует?

Comment: да, сначала была такая ошибка, но я объявил $getAllAnsw перед функцией

Comment: перед какой функцией? если изменили, то измените и код в вопросе

Comment: думаю в переменной `$getAllAnsw` не то что ожидается, т.к. теперь в переменной `$getKey`, то что вызывает `false` и перекидывает в данный блок. Проверьте что бы в  `$getAllAnsw` был хотя бы пустой массив.

Comment: обновил код,  причем функция срабатывает так что сообщение появляется опять "Выберите опрос", затем  "Выберите ответ", и клавиатура из запроса $getAllPoll, а не из $getAllAnswer

Comment: @ЕгорПодоляк, вероятно это происходит потому, что это условие `if($getPoll){}` срабатывает сразу, не дожидаясь пока вы что-то выберите